# Using The UIImagePickerController to select and upload a photo to server.

Tags: iphone

I am using the `Picker` controller with `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary`.

In the delegate `didFinishPickingImage` is called, but when I click on the cancel button it doesn't enter:

```
(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
```

This happens even though the controller is dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the class you think it is calling implements the proper delegate protocol.

This case should be UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, like this:

```
@interface YourClassViewController : UIViewController < UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
```

Comment: Hii , it does implement the  UIImagePickerControllerDelegate , since 
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo 
{ 
 NSLog(@" HomeMainViewController size %d :", image.size.width) ;
}
is been called.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the rest of UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.  When the cancel button is clicked, the picker will call -imagePickerControllerDidCancel: on its delegate.